# How to use the keys from a Hash to make a new Hash where each key's value is the key itself?

Tags: ruby, hash

So this is a trivial, but hopefully fun question.  I need to make a `Hash` with identical keys and values from the keys of an existing `Hash`.  Here's an example input along with my best attempt so far:

```
input = {'cat' => 'meow', 'dog' => nil}
Hash[*input.keys.map {|k| [k,k]}.flatten]
#=> {'cat' => 'cat', 'dog' => 'dog'}
```

I don't think this is particularly readable, so I was wondering if there was a better, more expressive syntax for doing this in Ruby, particularly one that might be more readable for future programmers who maintain the code?

This is how I would do the same thing in Python, and I find it to be slightly more readable:

```
dict([[a,a] for a in input])
```

But that could just be because I'm used to reading Python!

Looking for suggestions that will work with Ruby 1.8.6, which is the version I am constrained to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy a hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157399/how-do-i-copy-a-hash-in-ruby)

Comment: The input and desired output demonstrate that I am NOT asking how to copy a hash, I'm transforming it into a new hash based on a function.  I would gladly accept edits to the question title that would make this more clear, but it's a tricky problem to express concisely.

Comment: "Use the keys from a Hash to make a new Hash where each key's value is itself."

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out why I'd want a hash that has keys and values be the same.

Comment: I don't deny that it is pretty silly.  It's an argument to a rails method that is showing a select dropdown to the user.  I want the display name and input value to be the same and it takes a hash.

Comment: I thought that an [`<option>some text</option>`](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/OPTION.html) would default to returning the content of the tag. Rails overrides that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = {'cat' => 'meow', 'dog' => nil}
#=> {"cat"=>"meow", "dog"=>nil}
Hash[h.keys.map{|k| [k,k]}]
#=> {"cat"=>"cat", "dog"=>"dog"}
```

Here's another, a bit dirty way (and I think it works in 1.8.6):

```
h.merge(h){|k,v,v| k}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but I forgot to mention that I am constrained to ruby 1.8.6, which apparently doesn't have this `Hash` creation syntax.  Your answer works perfectly in ruby 1.8.7, but fails in ruby 1.8.6

Comment: Ah, I see. Take a look at `backports` gem then, I would expect such feature to be included there.

Comment: It does work, and points for brevity ... what is "dirty" about it?  Is there some pitfall there that I should be concerned about?

Comment: Not that I know of. Dirty because it's not intuitive and perhaps misusing `merge` method. I think I would go for your initial code (or Michael Kohl's inject-based) if needing 1.8.6 solution that someone else will read. But consider trying backports first.

Answer (score 2):

```
Hash[input.keys.zip(input.keys)] #=> {"cat"=>"cat", "dog"=>"dog"}
```

Or with inject:

```
input.keys.inject({}) { |h, k| h[k] = k ; h } #=> {"cat"=>"cat", "dog"=>"dog"}
```

The second also works in 1.8.6.