# What's the difference between Ruby's dup and clone methods?

Tags: ruby, clone, dup

The [Ruby docs for `dup`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) say:

> In general, `clone` and `dup` may have different semantics in descendent classes. While `clone` is used to duplicate an object, including its internal state, `dup` typically uses the class of the descendent object to create the new instance.

But when I do some test I found they are actually the same:

```
class Test
   attr_accessor :x
end

x = Test.new
x.x = 7
y = x.dup
z = x.clone
y.x => 7
z.x => 7
```

So what are the differences between the two methods?

Comment: I wish I knew not merely the difference in *what* `dup` and `clone` does, but *why* you'd use one rather than the other.

Comment: here is a good link also - https://coderwall.com/p/1zflyg

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Subclasses may override these methods to provide different semantics. In `Object` itself, there are two key differences.

First, `clone` copies the singleton class, while `dup` does not.

```
o = Object.new
def o.foo
  42
end

o.dup.foo   # raises NoMethodError
o.clone.foo # returns 42
```

Second, `clone` preserves the frozen state, while `dup` does not.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar
end
o = Foo.new
o.freeze

o.dup.bar = 10   # succeeds
o.clone.bar = 10 # raises RuntimeError
```

The [Rubinius implementation for these methods](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/alpha.rb#L189)
is often my source for answers to these questions, since it is quite clear, and a fairly compliant Ruby implementation.

Comment: In case anyone tries to change this again: the "singleton class", which is a well-defined term in Ruby, includes not only the singleton *methods*, but also any constants defined on the singleton class. Consider: `o = Object.new; class << o; A=5; end; puts ( class << o.clone; A; end ); puts ( class << o.dup; A; end )`.

Comment: great answer, followed by a great comment, but it led me on a wild goose chase to understand that syntax. this will help anyone else out there who might also be confused: http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the "singleton class" includes also any modules that have been `extend`ed on the original object. So `Object.new.extend(Enumerable).dup.is_a?(Enumerable)` returns false.

Comment: Although this answers does answer the question and states the differences. It's also worth noting that both methods are meant for different situations as stated by the [*Object#dup*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-dup-label-on+dup+vs+clone) documentation. The use case for *clone* is cloning an object with the intention to use it as that same instance (while having a different object id), while *dup* is intended to duplicate an object as base for an new instance.

Answer (score 220):

When dealing with ActiveRecord there's a significant difference too:

[`dup`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup) creates a new object without its id being set, so you can save a new object to the database by hitting `.save`

```
category2 = category.dup
#=> #<Category id: nil, name: "Favorites">
```

[`clone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-clone) creates a new object with the same id, so all the changes made to that new object will overwrite the original record if hitting `.save`

```
category2 = category.clone
#=> #<Category id: 1, name: "Favorites">
```

Comment: THIS answer is the one that has IMO the most important practical info... the other answers dwell on esoterica, whereas this answer pinpoints a critical practical difference.

Comment: The above is specific to ActiveRecord though; the distinction is far more subtle in standard Ruby.

Comment: @Stefan and @jvalanen : When i am applying `dup` and `clone` methods on my `ActiveRecord` object, i am getting reverse results of what you have mentioned in the answer. which means when i am using `dup`, it creates a new object with it's `id` being set and while using `clone` it creates an object without it's `id` being set. can you please look into it again and clearify ? . Thnx

Comment: Nothing has changed in Rails 5 either: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-clone. So I believe there's something special in your case...

Comment: However, `clone`ing a new record that has never been saved should be pretty safe then ? Can I build a "template object" this way, and clone it to save specific instances ?

Answer (score 31):

One difference is with frozen objects. The `clone` of a frozen object is also frozen (whereas a `dup` of a frozen object isn't).

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :x
end
x = Test.new
x.x = 7
x.freeze
y = x.dup
z = x.clone
y.x = 5 => 5
z.x = 5 => TypeError: can't modify frozen object
```

Another difference is with singleton methods. Same story here, `dup` doesn't copy those, but `clone` does.

```
def x.cool_method
  puts "Goodbye Space!"
end
y = x.dup
z = x.clone
y.cool_method => NoMethodError: undefined method `cool_method'
z.cool_method => Goodbye Space!
```

Comment: This was very useful to me. If you're creating a frozen constant value and passing it to something like this: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L248 (Rails cookie handling) then you can easily get an error when they unbeknownst to you they clone it and then attempt to modify the clone. duping your frozen value and passing that in allows you to at least guarantee that no one accidentally modifies your constant, without breaking Rack here.

Answer (score 5):

The [newer doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-dup-label-on+dup+vs+clone) includes a good example:

```
class Klass
  attr_accessor :str
end

module Foo
  def foo; 'foo'; end
end

s1 = Klass.new #=> #<Klass:0x401b3a38>
s1.extend(Foo) #=> #<Klass:0x401b3a38>
s1.foo #=> "foo"

s2 = s1.clone #=> #<Klass:0x401b3a38>
s2.foo #=> "foo"

s3 = s1.dup #=> #<Klass:0x401b3a38>
s3.foo #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<Klass:0x401b3a38>
```

Answer (score 4):

Both are nearly identical but clone does one more thing than dup. In clone, the frozen state of the object is also copied. In dup, it’ll always be thawed.

```
 f = 'Frozen'.freeze
  => "Frozen"
 f.frozen?
  => true 
 f.clone.frozen?
  => true
 f.dup.frozen?
  => false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use clone to do prototype-based programming in Ruby. Ruby's Object class defines both the clone method and dup method. Both clone and dup produce a shallow copy of the object it is copying; that is, the instance variables of the object are copied but not the objects they reference. I will demonstrate an example:

```
class Apple
  attr_accessor :color
  def initialize
    @color = 'red'
  end
end

apple = Apple.new
apple.color
 => "red"
orange = apple.clone
orange.color 
 => "red"
orange.color << ' orange'
 => "red orange" 
apple.color
 => "red orange"
```

Notice in the above example, the orange clone copies the state (that is, the instance variables) of the apple object, but where the apple object references other objects (such as the String object color), those references are not copied. Instead, apple and orange both reference the same object! In our example, the reference is the string object 'red'. When orange uses the append method, <<, to modify the existing String object, it changes the string object to 'red orange'. This in effect changes apple.color too, since they are both pointing to the same String object.

As a side note, the assignment operator, =, will assign a new object and thus destroy a reference. Here is a demonstration:

```
class Apple
  attr_accessor :color
  def initialize
    @color = 'red'
  end
end

apple = Apple.new
apple.color
=> "red"
orange = apple.clone
orange.color
=> "red"
orange.color = 'orange'
orange.color
=> 'orange'
apple.color
=> 'red'
```

In the above example, when we assigned a fresh new object to the color instance method of the orange clone, it no longer references the same object as apple. Hence, we can now modify the color method of orange without affecting the color method of apple, but if we clone another object from apple, that new object will reference the same objects in copied instance variables as apple.

dup will also produce a shallow copy of the object it is copying, and if you were to do the same demonstration shown above to dup, you will see it works exactly the same way. But there are two major differences between clone and dup. First, as others mentioned, clone copies the frozen state and dup does not. What does this mean? The term 'frozen' in Ruby is an esoteric term for immutable, which itself is a nomenclature in computer science, meaning that something cannot be changed. Thus, a frozen object in Ruby cannot be modified in any way; it is, in effect, immutable. If you attempt to modify a frozen object, Ruby will raise a RuntimeError exception. Since clone copies the frozen state, if you attempt to modify a cloned object, it will raise a RuntimeError exception. Conversely, since dup does not copy the frozen state, no such exception will occur, as we'll demonstrate:

```
class Apple
  attr_accessor :color
  def initialize
    @color = 'red'
  end
end

apple = Apple.new
apple.frozen?
 => false 
apple.freeze
apple.frozen?
 => true 
apple.color = 'crimson'
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Apple
apple.color << ' crimson' 
 => "red crimson" # we cannot modify the state of the object, but we can certainly modify objects it is referencing!
orange = apple.dup
orange.frozen?
 => false 
orange2 = apple.clone
orange2.frozen?
 => true 
orange.color = 'orange'
 => "orange" # we can modify the orange object since we used dup, which did not copy the frozen state
orange2.color = 'orange'
RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Apple # orange2 raises an exception since the frozen state was copied via clone
```

Second, and, more interestingly, clone copies the singleton class (and hence its methods)! This is very useful if you desire to undertake prototype-based programming in Ruby. First, let's show that indeed the singleton methods are copied with clone, and then we can apply it in an example of prototype-based programming in Ruby.

```
class Fruit
  attr_accessor :origin
  def initialize
    @origin = :plant
  end
end

fruit = Fruit.new
 => #<Fruit:0x007fc9e2a49260 @origin=:plant> 
def fruit.seeded?
  true
end
2.4.1 :013 > fruit.singleton_methods
 => [:seeded?] 
apple = fruit.clone
 => #<Fruit:0x007fc9e2a19a10 @origin=:plant> 
apple.seeded?
 => true
```

As you can see, the singleton class of the fruit object instance is copied to the clone. And hence the cloned object has access to the singleton method :seeded?. But this is not the case with dup:

```
apple = fruit.dup
 => #<Fruit:0x007fdafe0c6558 @origin=:plant> 
apple.seeded?
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `seeded?'
```

Now in prototype-based programming, you do not have classes which extend other classes and then create instances of classes whose methods derive from a parent class that serves as a blueprint. Instead, you have a base object and then you create a new object from the object with its methods and state copied over (of course, since we are doing shallow copies via clone, any objects the instance variables reference will be shared just as in JavaScript prototypes). You can then fill in or change the object's state by filling in the details of the cloned methods. In the below example, we have a base fruit object. All fruit have seeds, so we create a method number_of_seeds. But apples have one seed, and so we create a clone and fill in the details. Now when we clone apple, we not only cloned the methods but we cloned the state! Remember clone does a shallow copy of the state (instance variables). And because of that, when we clone apple to get a red_apple, red_apple will automatically have 1 seed! You can think of red_apple as an object that inherits from Apple, which in turn inherits from Fruit. Hence, that is why I capitalized Fruit and Apple. We did away with the distinction between classes and objects courtesy of clone.

```
Fruit = Object.new
def Fruit.number_of_seeds=(number_of_seeds)
  @number_of_seeds = number_of_seeds
end
def Fruit.number_of_seeds
  @number_of_seeds
end
 Apple = Fruit.clone
 => #<Object:0x007fb1d78165d8> 
Apple.number_of_seeds = 1
Apple.number_of_seeds
=> 1
red_apple = Apple.clone
 => #<Object:0x007fb1d892ac20 @number_of_seeds=1> 
red_apple.number_of_seeds
 => 1
```

Of course, we can have a constructor method in protoype-based programming:

```
Fruit = Object.new
def Fruit.number_of_seeds=(number_of_seeds)
  @number_of_seeds = number_of_seeds
end
def Fruit.number_of_seeds
  @number_of_seeds
end
def Fruit.init(number_of_seeds)
  fruit_clone = clone
  fruit_clone.number_of_seeds = number_of_seeds
  fruit_clone
end
Apple = Fruit.init(1)
 => #<Object:0x007fcd2a137f78 @number_of_seeds=1> 
red_apple = Apple.clone
 => #<Object:0x007fcd2a1271c8 @number_of_seeds=1> 
red_apple.number_of_seeds
 => 1
```

Ultimately, using clone, you can get something similar to the JavaScript prototype behavior.