# When to use dup, and when to use clone in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, clone, idioms, dup

[What's the difference between Ruby's dup and clone methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-differences-between-ruby-dup-and-clone-method) describes the difference in the behavior of `dup` and `clone`. But when should I use `dup`, and when should I use `clone` instead?

Examples from actual projects which discuss why they used dup rather than clone, or vice versa, would be ideal for this question.

Alternatively, an explanation of why the two different methods exist would be helpful. This could refer to statements from the creators of Ruby, or an examination of methods like `dup` and `clone` in languages that influenced Ruby.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Ruby's dup and clone methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true that `clone` copies the `frozen` state of an object, while `dup` does not:

```
o = Object.new
o.freeze

o.clone.frozen?
#=> true

o.dup.frozen?
#=> false
```

`clone` will also copy the singleton methods of the object while `dup` does not:

```
o = Object.new
def o.foo
  42
end

o.clone.respond_to?(:foo)
#=> true

o.dup.respond_to?(:foo)
#=> false
```

Which leads me to the assumption that `clone` is sometimes understood as to provide a "deeper" copy than `dup`. Here are some quotes about the topic:

[Comment on `ActiveRecord::Base#initialize_dup` from Rails 3](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L529-L533):

> Duped objects have no id assigned and are treated as new records. Note
>   that this is a "shallow" copy as it copies the object's attributes
>   only, not its associations. The extent of a "deep" copy is application
>   specific and is therefore left to the application to implement according
>   to its need.

[An article about deep copies in Ruby](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm):

> There is another method worth mentioning, `clone`. The `clone` method does the same thing as `dup` with one important distinction: it's expected that objects will override this method with one that can do deep copies.

[But then again, theres `deep_dup` in Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-2/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/deep_dup.rb):

> Returns a deep copy of object if it's duplicable. If it's not duplicable, returns `self`.

[and also `ActiveRecord::Core#dup` and `#clone` in Rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8b364715010c25ddb28500d5b4a612386c437eb3/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L297-L321):

> `clone` — Identical to Ruby's clone method.  This is a "shallow" copy. Be warned that your attributes are not copied. [...] If you need a copy of your attributes hash, please use the `#dup` method.

Which means that here, the word `dup` is used to refer to a deep clone again. As far as I can see, there seems to be no consensus in the community, except that you should use `clone` and `dup` in the case when you need a specific side effect of either one.

Finally, I see `dup` much more often in Ruby code than `clone`. I have never used `clone` so far, and I won't until I explicitly need to.

Comment: For now it looks to me like you've got to use `dup`, unless you have reasons to use `clone` (`dup` seems to be simpler). But maybe that's because I'm now concerned with duplicating a hash. So I don't care about frozen state and a singleton class.

Answer (score 5):

> Both DUP & CLONE can be used to create shallow copy of an object. Both copies the instance variables of obj. But we need to be selective in their usage.
>
> Few difference between these are
>
> 1) CLONE copies both FROZEN and TAINTED state of an object, where as DUP only copies TAINTED state of an object.
>
> 2) With CLONE you can copy any singleton methods of an object but DUP does not support this.
>
> CLONE is used to duplicate an object, including its internal state, DUP typically uses the class of the descendent object to create the new instance.
>
> I had some bitter experience while using DUP for duplicating an ActiveRecord row, this ended up in losing the original one the same worked fine with CLONE.

*As I wrapped myself in confusion, I found it clear in an [Article of Open Source is Wide Open](http://railsblogger.blogspot.com.br/2009/03/ruby-dup-vs-clone.html)*

Comment: "There are three manners to copy in Ruby: #dup, #clone and '='." - How does `=` copy?

Comment: I don't get deeper in how '=' copy, but it makes a shallow copy too. Here is a [good example](http://thingsaaronmade.com/blog/ruby-shallow-copy-surprise.html) for start, but in summary the assignment operator doesn't make a copy of the value, it simply copies the reference to the object

Comment: Just a note: `Marshal::load(Marshal.dump(foo))` works, but may cause trouble with database models.

Comment: Operator = does not make a shallow copy, it will just copy the object reference!  That statement is just plain wrong.  Also: the difference between #dup and #clone is just handling of the frozen state.  I think it is a bad idea to implement different copying algorithms for both - either it's both deep or shallow. And where are the numbers about a performance difference between the two?  I would be very surprised to see significant differences because both do basically the same.  Can you point at numbers?