# Prevent side effects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a << 5
a == [1,2,3,4] # returns false
```

How to assign `b` to `a` with `5` appended to the end without modifying `a` itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby variables hold *references* to objects and the `=` operator copies the *references*.

It seems you wish to [`clone`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-clone) `a`:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1,2,3,4]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):002:0> b = a.clone << 5
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):003:0> a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
irb(main):004:0> b
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Or maybe [`dup`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup), depending on what the OP wants. See also [What's the difference between Ruby's `dup` and `clone` methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-differences-between-ruby-dup-and-clone-method)

Answer (score 9):

Just sum two arrays:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a + [5]

# b == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# a == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually do it this way:

```
b = [*a, 5]
```

Comment: Or more simply: `b = *a, 5`