# What is the difference of Ruby's Array#to_a method

Tags: ruby, arrays

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
c = a.to_a
a.insert(0,0)  #=> [0,1,2,3,4]
b              #=> [0,1,2,3,4]
c              #=> [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Why the output of array `b` and `c` is the same? If I want to get a copy of array `a`, not a reference one, which method should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do

```
b = a.dup
```

---

OLD POST
You can try this if there is no easier way

```
b = a.map {|x| x}
```

It works

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > a = [1,2,3]      => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3-p448 :002 > b = a            => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3-p448 :003 > c = a.map{|x| x} => [1, 2, 3] 
1.9.3-p448 :004 > a<<0             => [1, 2, 3, 0] 
1.9.3-p448 :005 > b                => [1, 2, 3, 0] 
1.9.3-p448 :006 > c                => [1, 2, 3]
```

But it is a shallow copy though.

According to [this post](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/132393), `a.dup` is the easier way.

Comment: Why not simply do `b = a.dup`?

Comment: @LBg am new to ruby myself, just noticed that one too

Answer (score 4):

> Why the output of array b and c is the same?

Because all three local variables referencing the same objects,as below:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
c = a.to_a
a.object_id
# => 72187200
b.object_id
# => 72187200
c.object_id
# => 72187200
```

> If i want to get a copy of array a, not a reference one , which method should i use?

Then use `a.dup`.Here documented [**`Object#dup`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup)

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a.dup
c = a.dup
a.object_id
# => 82139270
b.object_id
# => 82139210
c.object_id
# => 82134600
a.insert(0,0) # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
c # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> [**`Array#to_a`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_a) says : Returns self.If called on a subclass of Array, converts the receiver to an Array object.

So it will not be helpful as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`Array#to_a` returns `self`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_a), so both variables contain a reference to the same Array object. In order to get a new Array with the same contents, you can use either [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) or [`clone`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-clone) ([read about the differences between `dup` and `clone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods)):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.dup
a << 4
a  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
b  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Note, however, that the *same object references are stored in the new array*. This means if you mutate the objects themselves they will still change in both arrays:

```
a = ['foo', 'bar']
b = a.dup
a[0] << 'baz'
a  #=> ["foobaz", "bar"]
b  #=> ["foobaz", "bar"]
```

This is because `dup` and `clone` are [shallow-copies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy).

Answer (score 1):

`Array#to_a` returns the receiver. That is why `b` and `c` refer to the same thing. Regarding why `to_a` returns the original array, in principle, it could be defined one or the other way,   but I guess one use case for `to_a` is to apply it to a variable that is potentially `nil` to ensure it becomes an array.

```
some_value.to_a # => `[]` if `some_value` is `nil`
```

In such use case, you don't need to replace the array with another one in case the receiver is already an array. That would be performantly more preferable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that variables are merely references to data. Variables are stored in memory; variables keep address of where they are located in a memory. So when you do:

```
a = b
```

Those two variables point to the same memory location, hence if you alter `a`, `b` is altered as well because it is the same object.

There are a few ways to force Ruby to create another copy of the object. The most popular one is the `dup` method mentioned by LBg. Note however that it is only creating a shallow copy. If you run:

```
a = ['foo','bar', []]
b = a.dup

a << 'blah'
b              #=> ['foo', 'bar', []] as expected but

b[3] << blah

a              #=> ['foobar', 'bar', ['blah]]
```

The reason for that is that array is in fact an array of references and nested array has not been duplicated when performing `dup`, so they are the same object.

To create a deep copy of an object, you can use the Marshall module:

```
b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))
```

However, usually you don't really need to do this. Also, some objects cannot be duplicated (e.g. symbols).