# reference object and preserve its original value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@hac = HacCfgGroup.find(1897)
b = @hac
>> @hac.status
=> 2


>> @hac.status = 4
=> 4
>> b.status
=> 4
```

HacCfgGroup is an object with many attributes.
How to let b keep its original value? spent so long on it still cannot figure out how to keep an object without changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/copy-object-in-ruby

there are some explainations. 
more precisely clone is the answer

Answer (score 0):

`b` and `@hac` are pointing at the same object. Try `b = @hac.dup` creating a duplicate object.

Comment: seems not work??       I can still modify the b via @hac even though they are dup

Comment: See the difference between `clone` and `dup` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods.