# ruby on rails: suddenly failing method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not sure how to present my issue best without posting the whole framework.
I have a method `duplicate!` which should duplicate an object (channel). Usually it works but there is one channel where the method fails and I just don't understand why:

```
def duplicate!
    channel = Channel.new do |c|
      c.title = title << ' (copy)'
      c.description = description
    end
    channel.nodes += nodes
    playlist.nodes.each { |n| channel.playlist.playlist_items.create(node: n) }
    channel
  end
```

As said nearly all channels duplicate without a problem, but now I have one channel which fails to get duplicated:

```
2.3.0 :002 > channel.duplicate!
NoMethodError: undefined method `playlist_items' for nil:NilClass
    from /var/www/app/models/channel.rb:110:in `block in duplicate!'
    from /var/www/app/models/channel.rb:110:in `each'
    from /var/www/app/models/channel.rb:110:in `duplicate!'
```

Every Channel has Nodes and a Playlist, the error producing Channel has too.
I don't really understand the error; how can this method fail depended on the object to duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is failing is because one of your channels dont have a playlist record. So this line is failing

```
playlist.nodes.each { |n| channel.playlist.playlist_items.create(node: n) }
```

for the channel that does not have a `playlist` record `channel.playlist` returns `nil` so when you do `channel.playlist.playlist_items` you are calling `nil.playlist_items`, and since `nil` does not have the method you get an error.

You could just do this instead of making your on duplicate method fyi

```
 copy_of_channel5 = channel5.dup
```

This will duplicate the object

You could also do this

```
copy_of_channel5 = channel5.clone
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods) for a details explanation of the difference between the 2

**Trouble Shooting***

1. Go to your gem file and add this line `gem 'pry'`
2. Run bundle
3. Replace this line `playlist.nodes.each { |n| channel.playlist.playlist_items.create(node: n) }` with the below code.

   playlist.nodes.each {|n| binding.pry}
4. once the execution console pauses type in the console `channel.playlist` then press enter and post the output.

Comment: Yes, it has a playlist record and that record has nodes in it.

Comment: `2.3.0 :005 > channel.playlist.nodes.count
 => 8 `

Comment: You are absolutely certain that every single channel has a playlist record?

Comment: are you using pry?

Comment: In you console run this `Channel.all.select {|c| c.playlist.nil?}` and tell me what the output is.

Comment: no, not using pry.
channel is not nil: `2.3.0 :006 > channel.playlist
 => #<Playlist id: 122, channel_id: 121, created_at: "2016-07-11 09:46:29", updated_at: "2016-07-11 09:46:29"> `

Comment: Let me know what the output of that code is, one you run it

Comment: `Channel.all.select {|c| c.playlist.nil?}  => []`

Comment: Ok that is strange then

Comment: Honestly I have no idea why this works at all I don't see where playlist is ever getting created. you are doing this `channel = Channel.new` setting a few values on it then calling `channel.playlist` unless the `playlist` is getting made somewhere else I don't see how this code is not failing all the time.

Comment: a Channel `has_one :playlist` and a Playlist `has_many :playlist_items`

Comment: Ok I am going to edit my answer with a section called trouble shoot follow those steps

Comment: Since the failing Channel is on a production system, is it possible to bring it into a format I can easily export it to the development system? Since I don't know the difference to working Channels I can not reproduce the error on develop

Comment: Wait so all the out put you showed me from all those commands I gave you were from you local develop environment?

Comment: No, these were from production. But a code deploy on production would be less preferable than debugging on develop

Comment: Ok well you can still try the trouble shooting on your local, but I can guarantee you that there is a nil playlist some where and its probably on this line `channel.playlist.playlist_items.create(node: n) }`

Comment: I must be missing something here, but thats all I have good luck please update when you find the issue. I know for a fact that the only reason you get that error is because you are calling a method on `nil` so somewhere you are calling `playlist_items` on `nil` . Cheers!

Comment: You were right, one Node which should be added as a playlist_item was inconsistent. I don't know where the inconsistency came from but it is solved now.

Comment: Glad I could help