# How to delete a element from two arrays independently which has been copied from one another?

Tags: ruby

> a = [1,2,3]

=> [1, 2, 3]

> b = a

=> [1, 2, 3]

> b.delete(1)

=> 1

> b

=> [2, 3]

> a

=> [2, 3]

Array A has given [1,2,3] values, and Array A has been copied to Array B

Then whenever I delete a element from Array B , the element gets deleted from Array A too

eg : If i delete element 1 from array B ,it gets deleted from array A too..

How to avoid this, How to delete an element from these arrays separately ?

Comment: "Array A has been copied to Array B" – Where? There is no copy operation in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dup](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) to create a copy of the array.

```
a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
b = a.dup
=> [1, 2, 3]
a.delete(1)
=> 1
a
=> [2, 3]
b
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

EDIT:

As to why this is, when you assign `b = a`, you assign `b` to be a reference to `a`. This means that both variables refer the same underlying object. With `dup` we are forcing Ruby to create a copy of `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked and can I know why it was happening?

Comment: On the subtleties of clone vs dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the note, I'll remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a shallow copy in b, so the contents aren't copied. To copy them, use Object::clone: `b = a.clone`.