# Ruby on Rails: how to copy objects from one category to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to copy some latest recipients (subscribers) to a new category in my newsletter app. I ran following lines of code in Rails console but instead of copying recipients to new category it moved latest 10 recipients to new category. It looks like `recipient.clone` is not working. I'm using Ruby `v2.0.0` and Rails `v3.2.11`.

```
recipients = Recipient.where(category_id: 54).order('created_at DESC').take(10)
recipients.each{ |recipient| 
  @recipient_clone = recipient.clone
  @recipient_clone.category_id=63
  @recipient_clone.save
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried

```
recipients.each{ |recipient| 
  recipient.freeze
  @recipient_clone = recipient.dup
  @recipient_clone = @recipient_clone.category_id=63
  @recipient_clone.save
}
```

but it gives `NoMethodError: private method 'initialize_dup' called` error.

Comment: Have you tried with `recipient.dup` instead?

Comment: yes but it gives `NoMethodError` error

Comment: As @Iceman says.  Clone will keep the `id` field so when you save you're updating an existing record.  `dup` is better for your purposes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods

Comment: @Iceman I tried `recipient.freeze` before `recipient.dup` but it raises same `NoMethodError`

Comment: full error message: `NoMethodError: private method 'initialize_dup' called for #<Recipient:0x007fd20e490808>`

Comment: Maybe `recipient.dup` not working due to a [bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9417) in Rails version we are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the cleanest way, but it should work :)

```
recipients = Recipient.where(category_id: 54).order('created_at DESC').take(10)
recipients.each{ |recipient| 
  @recipient_clone = Recipient.new(recipient.attributes.except(:id))
  @recipient_clone.category_id=63
  @recipient_clone.save
}
```

Comment: Yay, this should work. We used a similar approach `Recipient.new(:email => r.email, :first_name => r.first_name ....)` as we had to exclude many attributes and it worked.

Comment: I'm waiting if we can get a better explanation why `recipient.dup` did not work otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You said you are using Rails v3.2.11, right? This issue says you should use Rails 3.2.13 or greater. https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/294