# Create or update record for ArchivedUser

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a backup table of `users`, called `archived users`. It creates the ArchivedUser by taking a hash of the current users attributes (self) and merging in the `self.id` as the `user_id`.

When a user is reinstated, their record as an `ArchivedUser` still remains in the `ArchivedUser` table. If the user gets deleted a second time, it should update any attributes that have changed.

Currently, it throws a validation error:
`Validation failed: User has already been taken`, as the `self.id` already exists in the `ArchivedUser` table.

What is a better way to handle an object where you update an existing object if possible, or create a new record if it doesn't exist. I am using Rails 4 and have tried `find_or_create_by` but it throws an error

`Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'device_details.device_app_version'`

which is odd, as that column exists in both tables and doesn't get modified.

User Delete Method

```
  # creates ArchivedUser with the exact attributes of the User
  # object and merges self.id to fill user_id on ArchivedUser
  if ArchivedUser.create!(
    self.attributes.merge(user_id: self.id)
  )
```

Thanks for taking a peek!

Answer (score 0):

If your `archived_users` table is truly acting as a backup for users and not adding any additional functionality, I would ditch the `ArchiveUser` model and simply add an `archived` boolean on the `User` model to tell whether or not the user is archived.

That way you don't have to deal with moving an object to another table and hooking into a delete callback.

However, if your `ArchiveUser` model does offer some different functionality compared to `User`, another option would be to use [single table inheritence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) to differentiate the type of user. In this case, you could have `User` govern all users, and then distinguish between a user being, for example, an `ActiveUser` or an `ArchivedUser`.

This takes more setup and can be a bit confusing if you haven't worked with STI, but it can be useful when two similar models need to differ only slightly.

---

That being said, if you want to keep your current setup, I believe there are a few issues I see with your code:

1. If you are going to create an object from an existing object, it's good practice to [duplicate the object (`dup`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24650062/2241124). That way the `id` won't be automatically set and can be auto-incremented.
2. If you truly have deleted the `User` record from the database, there's no reason to store a reference to its `id` because it's gone. But if you aren't actually deleting the record, you should definitely just use a boolean attribute to determine whether or not the user is active or archived.
3. I don't have enough context here as to why `find_or_create_by` isn't working, but if it were the case, then I would keep it as simple as possible. Don't use all the attributes, but just the consistent ones (like `id`) that you know will return the proper result.
4. `if ArchivedUser.create! # ...` is problematic. The bang after create (i.e. `create!`) will throw an error if the record could not be created, making the `if` pointless. So, either use `if` if you don't want errors thrown and want to handle the condition in which the record was not created. Or use `create!` without `if` if you do want to throw an error.