# Ruby's dup and clone method for Class methods

Tags: ruby

I have read a couple of questions about Ruby dup and clone method [Ruby dup and clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods). I understand that `dup` doesn't copy the `singleton` methods and clone does for any object.

I am trying to check w.r.t class methods but found it bit confusing:-

```
class User
  def self.active
   'all active users'
  end
end

DupUser = User.dup
DupUser.active #=> all active users'

CloneUser = User.clone
CloneUser.active #=> all active users'
```

As far as I know, class methods are just singleton methods too, then why does `User.dup` copied the `active` method i.e actually a singleton method of `User`.

Comment: What is your question, though?

Comment: @PeterCamilleri please check the question, I think I missed adding complete details.

Comment: Very good. I did not see the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[By design](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/3527c05a8f4e189772cdac17f166bd9626c24661/spec/ruby/core/module/initialize_copy_spec.rb), singleton methods *are* retained when `dup` is called on a Class or Module, which is what you're doing in your example. When you `dup` an instance, singleton methods are not retained:

```
user = User.new

# This is a singleton method on an Object
def user.active
  'all active users'
end

cloned_user = user.clone
cloned_user.active # => 'all active users'

duped_user = user.dup
duped_user.active # => undefined method `active' for #<User:0x00007fee1f89ae30> (NoMethodError)
```

## Notes

- `def object.method` behaves the same as `object.extend(module)`. Methods from `module` are not `dup`ed (with the same caveat for calling `dup` on Classes or Modules).
- `dup` and `clone` internally call `initialize_copy`, so that's a starting point for finding how a Class overrides `dup` or `clone`.
- Later versions of ruby added `initialize_clone` and `initialize_dup` to fine tune overrides of `clone` and `dup`.