# ruby clone an object

Tags: ruby, class, clone, dup

I need to clone an existing object and change that cloned object.
The problem is that my changes change original object.
Here's the code:

```
require "httparty"

class Http
  attr_accessor :options
  attr_accessor :rescue_response
  include HTTParty
  def initialize(options)
    options[:path] = '/' if options[:path].nil? == true
    options[:verify] = false
    self.options = options

    self.rescue_response = {
      :code => 500
    }
  end

  def get
    self.class.get(self.options[:path], self.options)
  end

  def post
    self.class.post(self.options[:path], self.options)
  end

  def put
    self.class.put(self.options[:path], self.options)
  end

  def delete
    self.class.put(self.options[:path], self.options)
  end

end
```

Scenario:

```
test = Http.new({})

test2 = test

test2.options[:path] = "www"

p test2
p test
```

Output:

```
#<Http:0x00007fbc958c5bc8 @options={:path=>"www", :verify=>false}, @rescue_response={:code=>500}>
#<Http:0x00007fbc958c5bc8 @options={:path=>"www", :verify=>false}, @rescue_response={:code=>500}>
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can I ask what your are even trying to do with this monkey patch?  I'm trying to test your code and they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You want `.clone` or perhaps `.dup`

```
test2 = test.clone
```

But depending on your purposes, but in this case, you probably want `.clone`
see [What's the difference between Ruby's dup and clone methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods#10183477)

The main difference is that `.clone` also copies the objects singleton methods and frozen state.

On a side note, you can also change

```
options[:path] = '/' if options[:path].nil? # you don't need "== true"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to clone here, you just need to make a new instance.

Right here:

```
test = Http.new({})
test2 = test
```

you don't have two instances of Http, you have one. You just have two variables pointing to the same instance.

You could instead change it to this, and you wouldn't have the problem.

```
test = Http.new({})
test2 = Http.new({})
```

If, however, you used a shared `options` argument, that's where you'd encounter an issue:

```
options = { path: nil }
test = Http.new(options)

# options has been mutated, which may be undesirable
puts options[:path] # => "/"
```

To avoid this "side effect", you could change the initialize method to use a clone of the options:

```
def initialize(options)
  options = options.clone
  # ... do other stuff
end
```

You could also make use of the splat operator, which is a little more cryptic but possibly more idiomatic:

```
def initialize(**options)
  # do stuff with options, no need to clone
end
```

You would then call the constructor like so:

```
options = { path: nil }
test = Http.new(**options)
puts test.options[:path] # => "/"

# the original hasn't been mutated
puts options[:path] # => nil
```

Comment: good points here, although it is unclear what the purpose of the OP is ultimately trying to do with this monkey patch.  I couldn't even get the `get` method to work.