# How do I get a fresh copy of an array in each iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I cannot understand the following behavior

```
<% filter.each do |f| %>
   <% aux = @taxon_ids %>
   <%= check_box_tag "filter_taxon", aux << f[:id], @taxon_ids.include?(f[:id]) %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

for each loop of my function the `aux` var is not re-initializing. Indeed there is accumulating each id in him self.

Comment: are you modifying `@taxon_ids` in the view? Otherwise I don't see why this would be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're assigning a `new` object (or one of the literal shorthands like `[]`) then Ruby assignment is by reference, look:

```
[14] pry(main)> x = []          
=> []
[15] pry(main)> y = x           
=> []
[16] pry(main)> y << 1          
=> [1]
[17] pry(main)> x               
=> [1]
```

If you want your own copy of that array then use the `.dup` or `.clone` method:

```
aux = @taxon_ids.dup
```

Comment: For additional info on `#dup` vs `#clone` check out these links: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-dup-label-on+dup+vs+clone and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183370/whats-the-difference-between-rubys-dup-and-clone-methods