# Modifying a hash with multiple occurrences

Tags: ruby, hash, mutable

`a` is a hash. `s` is an array where I want to push the hash `a` iteratively. The idea is to retain the value of each iteratively pushed hash independently. Here is what I tried.

```
a = {:a=> 1, :b=>2}

s = []
s << a
s << a     # => [{:b=>2, :a=>1}, {:b=>2, :a=>1}]
a[:b] = 3
s          # => [{:b=>3, :a=>1}, {:b=>3, :a=>1}]

t = []
t.push(a)    # => [{:b=>3, :a=>1}]
t.push(a)    # => [{:b=>3, :a=>1}, {:b=>3, :a=>1}]
a[:b] = 4
t            # => [{:b=>4, :a=>1}, {:b=>4, :a=>1}]
```

The above doesn't give me the solution: Changing `a` changes the values in the elements inside the array which were previously pushed. After pushing `a` to `s` twice, I changed `a[:b]` from `2` to `3`, and all the elements reflected the change. Suggestion for this please.

Comment: Essentially dup of [How do I copy a hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157399/how-do-i-copy-a-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
s << Hash[a]
```

This will copy the Hash and allow you to change the original.

Comment: Similarly to `#dup` this only makes a shallow copy. If `a` had an element `:c => [1,2]` and after the copy he modified `a[:c] << 3`, then the copy pushed onto his array will also see that change

Answer (score 5):

Use [dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) every time you're adding to `s`

```
s << a.dup
```

The `dup` method will create shallow copy of hash.

Update:

In case if the shallow copy doesn't satisfy the requirements, then use Marshaling

```
s << Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(a) )
```

Comment: [`Object#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) only makes a shallow copy. If `a` had an element `:c => [1,2]` and after the copy he modified `a[:c] << 3`, then the copy pushed onto his array will also see that change.

Comment: @dbenhur, you're right, see the update