# Weird behaviour copying objects

Tags: ruby, deep-copy

I'm trying to deep copy an object which holds a 3D array. But it isn't working as expected.

```
class A
    def initialize
        @a = [[[1]], [[2]]]
    end

    def modify3D
        @a[0][0] = @a[1][0]
    end

    def modify2D
        @a[0] = @a[1]
    end

    def dup
        copy = super
        copy.make_independent!
        copy
    end

    def make_independent!
        @a = @a.dup
    end

    def show
        print "\n#{@a}"
    end
end

a = A.new
b = a.dup
#a.modify2D
b.show
a.modify3D
b.show
```

In this case b is changed by the modify3D call on a.

```
[[[1]], [[2]]]
[[[2]], [[2]]]
```

If I uncomment modify2D line everything works fine.

```
[[[1]], [[2]]]
[[[1]], [[2]]]
```

Could someone pls explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your copy isn't deep enough.  Array#dup only duplicates the array itself, not the array elements.  You end up with two different arrays that still share the same elements.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157635/238886) I showed how to use [marshaling](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Marshal.html) to do a deep copy.  This method does all the work:

```
def deep_copy(o)
  Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(o))
end
```

deep_copy works for any object that can be marshaled. Most built-in data types (Array, Hash, String, &c.) can be marshaled.  Any object which instance variables can be marshaled can itself be marshaled.

Having defined deep_copy, then replace this line:

```
b = a.dup
```

with this:

```
b = deep_copy(a)
```

and it ought to work as you expect.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, but I still cannot explain why uncommenting that lines makes it work. According with your explanation, it shouldn't.