# How can I get my array to only be manipulated locally (within a function) in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, scope

Why is my array globally manipulated, when I run the below ruby code? And how can I get arrays to be manipulated only within the function's scope?

```
a = [[1,0],[1,1]]

def hasRowsWithOnlyOnes(array)
  array.map { |row|
    return true if row.keep_if{|i| i != 1 } == []
  }
  false;
end

puts a.to_s
puts hasRowsWithOnlyOnes(a)
puts a.to_s
```

`$ ruby test.rb` output:

```
[[1, 0], [1, 1]]
true
[[0], []]
```

I can't get it to work. I've even tried `.select{true}` and assign it to a new name. How does the scope work in Ruby for Arrays?
Just for reference, `$ ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: You are so new to Ruby that I don't know if the answers will mean anything to you yet, but please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872110/is-ruby-pass-by-reference-or-by-value and tell us if it helps you to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: change `keep_if` to `select` to get your code working as required but much better to use @WayneConrad's recommendation below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## It's not a scope problem, it's an argument passing problem

- All variables in Ruby are references to objects.
- When you pass an object to a method, a copy of that object's reference is made and passed to the object.

That means that the variable `array` in your method and the top-level variable `a` refer to the exact same Array.  Any changes made to `array` will be also visible as changes to `a`, since both variables refer to the same object.

Your method does modify the array by calling [Array#keep_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-keep_if). The `keep_if` method modifies the array in-place.

## The fix

The best fix for this is to make it so that your method does not modify the array that was passed in. This can be done pretty neatly using the [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) and [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) methods:

```
def has_a_row_with_only_ones(array)
  array.any? do |row|
    row.all? { |e| e == 1 }
  end
end
```

This code says that the method returns true if, for any row, every element in that row is 1.  These methods do not modify the array.  More important, they communicate the method's intent clearly.

## The poor workaround

If you want the method to act as through a copy of the array were passed to it, so that the array can be modified without that modification being visible outside the method, then you can make a deep copy of the array.  As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157399/how-do-i-copy-a-hash-in-ruby/4157635#4157635), you can define this method to make a deep copy:

```
def deep_copy(o)
  Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(o))
end
```

Then, at the top of the method, make the deep copy:

```
def has_a_row_with_only_ones(array)
  array = deep_copy(array)
  # code that modifies array
end
```

This should be avoided because it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is **pass by value**

Via [sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-scope-in-ruby/)

> Ruby has variables defined within different scopes, which you probably
>   know already. I found that most tutorials describe them briefly (the
>   variable types), but they fail to mention precisely what their scope
>   is.

Here are the details:

Class variable (`@@a_variable`): Available from the class definition and any sub-classes. Not available from anywhere outside.

Instance variable (`@a_variable`): Available only within a specific object, across all methods in a class instance. Not available directly from class definitions.

Global variable (`$a_variable`): Available everywhere within your Ruby script.

Local variable (`a_variable`): It depends on the scope. You’ll be working with these most and thus encounter the most problems, because their scope depends on various things.

Comment: `a` is not global. Ruby globals start with `$` (and should not be used whatsoever).