# Initialize Ruby hash with a constant value

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-attributes

Actually I want to use such constructs in chef attributes, where I initialize a structure with a constant and modify it

```
init_value = { "a" => { "b" => "c" } }
prepare = init_value
prepare["a"]["x"] = "y"
```

now init_value also contains `["a"]["x"] = "y"`, so when I prepare a new value

```
prepare = init_value
prepare["a"]["y"] = "x"
```

so `prepare["a"]` contains the keys `["b", "x", "y"]`.

How can I initialize prepare with a constant without quoting the constant, so that in the last step, `prepare["a"]` only contains the two keys `["b","y"]`?

Comment: seems that the only practical way is `prepare = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(init_value))`. I wouldn't even call this copy. It seems that ruby totally lacks a real "deep copy" function for hashes. If you know a method please propose one!

Comment: Marshal is, unfortunately, the way to do a deep copy. Because even `dup` and then `freeze` will not stop modification of the values themselves, only assignment to keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the initial hash into a method. This way, the method always returns a "fresh" hash:

```
def init_value
  {"a"=>{"b"=>"c"}}
end

prepare = init_value
prepare["a"]["x"] = "y"
prepare
#=> {"a"=>{"b"=>"c", "x"=>"y"}}

prepare = init_value
prepare["a"]["y"] = "x"
prepare
#=> {"a"=>{"b"=>"c", "y"=>"x"}}
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution (I can't believe I overlooked this) I was so focused on the fact that the OP and other commenters seemed sure deep copying was not something that was supported.

Comment: Thanks to you all! I think we actually found what I and possibly some more have been searching for! Good Teamwork @engineersmnky

Answer (score 3):

Extracted from Rails 4.2.7

- [`Object#deep_dup`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/deep_dup) *"Returns a deep copy of object if it’s duplicable. If it’s not duplicable, returns self."*
- [`Hash#deep_dup`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Hash/deep_dup) *"Returns a deep copy of hash."*
- [`Array#deep_dup`](https://apidock.com/rails/Array/deep_dup) *"Returns a deep copy of array."*

Implementation:

```
class Object
  def duplicable?
    true
  end
  def deep_dup
    duplicable? ? dup : self
  end
end 

class Hash
   def deep_dup
     each_with_object(dup) do |(key, value), hash|
       hash[key.deep_dup] = value.deep_dup
     end
  end
end

class Array
  def deep_dup
    map { |it| it.deep_dup }
  end
end

# Not duplicable? 
# if ruby version < 2.0 also add Class and Module as they were not duplicable until 2.0
[Method, Symbol, FalseClass, TrueClass, NilClass, Numeric, BigDecimal].each do |m|
  m.send(:define_method, :duplicable?, ->{false})
end
```

Then you could use a method for `init_value` so that `deep_dup` is always called and you can't accidentally forget

```
#since you asked for a constant
INIT_VALUE = { "a" => { "b" => "c" } }.freeze

def init_value 
  INIT_VALUE.deep_dup 
end
```

And usage as such

```
prepare = init_value
prepare["a"]["x"] = "y"

prepare2 = init_value
prepare2["a"]["y"] = "x"

prepare
#=> {"a"=>{"b"=>"c", "x"=>"y"}}
prepare2
#=> {"a"=>{"b"=>"c", "y"=>"x"}}
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonable answer. I will try it tomorrow and approve if it works for me.

Comment: @ikrabbe depending on your implementation checkout Stefan's answer as it provides the same functionality with none of the code. That being said I will leave this hear as an example of "deep copying" since it seemed like a hot topic on this post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a "deep copy" of init_value when assigning to prepare.

see:
[How do I copy a hash in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157399/how-do-i-copy-a-hash-in-ruby)

Comment: please add an example of how to do it, then I will vote for your answer. Actually the answer you quoted does not contain usefull examples. I gave a minimal example that can easily be converted into a code driven answer, as Ruby actually seems to lack a real deep copy function.