# Changing multidimensional hash value and it's still equal

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to update a multidimensinal hash and then compare the new hash with the old one, but no matter what value I change they still show up as equal. Is there an efficient way to compare every value in two hashes and return false if one isn't true

```rb
hash1 = {foo: {bar: "baz"}}
hash2 = hash1
hash2[:foo][:bar] = "foz"
hash2 == hash1 # This should be false but is returning true
```

Comment: They're the same object. Altering `hash2` alters `hash1`. If they were actually different, they would not show as equal.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4157635/2166798

Comment: Are you using Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike assigning to simple primitive objects like integers, when you assign a variable to a hash, it will point to the same hash object. 
So, `hash2` is pointing on the same object as `hash1` in memory.
If you need them to be structurally the same but are different objects, you need to copy the first hash deeply.

```rb
def deep_copy(hash)
  Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))
end

hash1 = {foo: {bar: "baz"}}
hash2 = deep_copy(hash1)
hash2[:foo][:bar] = "foz"
hash2 == hash1
```